Keycloak standard auth plus google and outlook grant in React
On the backend I have java quarkus and on the frontend React. I am using keycloak for authentication. I implemented standard login with keycloak and react, and it works fine. Users are redirected to keycloak login page if they are not logged in, and that's fine.
But, as my application has calendar inside it, I want to integrate google calendar and outlook calendar also, so when I create event in my calendar, it is synced also with these 2 if user gave access to them.
My question is, can I handle it with keycloak, so only for granting access for google and outlook, and not mix up access tokens.
